# Kindle Fire Permissions

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

I submitted an app to Amazon Store, Amazon approved for Amazon store but not for kindle fire. 
After read https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire I check my manifest but I don't know what is the problem, I have removed all references of phone/gps features...
Only I have permissions like:

- android.permission.GET_TASKS
- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES

`READ_CONTACTS` is allowed ?

Comment: All this permissioos are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all of those permissions are allowed. It more likely has to do with your target version. What version of Android are you using? Their emails are generally pretty specific. Did they mention it being a permissions issue?

Comment: @cdsap - This is not an answer.